# How to make UITests and api interact

Tags: ios, xctest, xcuitest

I want to write test cases for my iOS application. I have managed to write UI tests but I am really getting confused as to how to make my application wait for the api to end. Just for example, UI tests are going on and at some point it presses a signup button and post call is done. Now how do I manage the callback from that api into UI tests.

I am aware of expectations which helps to manage the async calls but I do not know how to adjust this into UI tests.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the action returning. e.g. in case of a login, you will be redirected to a new view. So you could simply test for the existance of a know element.

```
let goLabel = app.staticTexts["Go!"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWithObject: goLabel, handler: nil)
```